# Informatica XML generation issue

Tags: xml, generator, informatica

In my target XML i am getting one element multiple entries which is having same value. It is applicable for all my data. I want to show single entry for the element in my XML. It should not impact my other elements. Plz suggest.need to achive this with informatica itself.no sciripting.

Comment: Show your code to check

Comment: i think you can de-duplicate using srt, agg combo, use sorter to get distinct value. like Mr. Gopta said, more info will help